# Error Connecting to SQLServer - Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, freetds, pymssql

I am using the following code to connect to the SQL server database from my application.

```
 try:
        self.__db_conn = pymssql.connect(self.__db_host, self.__db_user, self.__db_pass, self.__db_name)
        self.__db_cursor = self.__db_conn.cursor(as_dict=True)
    except pymssql.DatabaseError as e:
        print("Error: Could not connect to ODSREAD Database : %S", e)
```

and when I execute, I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Could not connect to ODSREAD Database : %S (18452, b'Login failed. 
The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.DB-Lib error message 20018,
severity 14:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error message 20002,
severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (ods.domain.net:1433)\n')
```

I have tried with `pyodbc` also and the code is as follows:

```
__db_driver = '{FreeTDS}'
__db_ip = ODS_IP
__db_port = ODS_PORT
__db_dbname = ODS_DBNAME
__db_username = ODS_USERNAME
__db_password = ODS_PASSWORD
__db_conn = None
__db_cursor = None
__connect_url = None

connectUrl = 'DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server};PORT={port};DATABASE={db_name};UID={username};PWD={password};TDS_VERSION=7.0'.format(
            driver=self.__db_driver,
            server=self.__db_ip,
            port=self.__db_port,
            db_name=self.__db_dbname,
            username=self.__db_username,
            password=self.__db_password
        )
self.__db_conn = pyodbc.connect(self.__connect_url)
```

Here also, I am getting errors like this:

```
 pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Login failed.
 The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication. (18452) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Seems like it is taking the Windows Authentication instead of the driver specified. I am running this on a Linux (CentOS 7.6) server and hence I am not able to use Windows authentication.

How can I fix this error?

Adding `freetds.conf`

```
[global]
        # TDS protocol version
;       tds version = 4.2

        # Whether to write a TDSDUMP file for diagnostic purposes
        # (setting this to /tmp is insecure on a multi-user system)
;       dump file = /tmp/freetds.log
;       debug flags = 0xffff

        # Command and connection timeouts
;       timeout = 10
;       connect timeout = 10

        # If you get out-of-memory errors, it may mean that your client
        # is trying to allocate a huge buffer for a TEXT field.
        # Try setting 'text size' to a more reasonable limit
        text size = 64512
        use ntlmv2 = yes
# A typical Sybase server
[egServer50]
        host = symachine.domain.com
        port = 5000
        tds version = 5.0

# A typical Microsoft server
[egServer70]
        host = ntmachine.domain.com
        port = 1433
        tds version = 7.0
```

and `odbcinst.ini` has the following

```
[PostgreSQL]
Description=ODBC for PostgreSQL
Driver=/usr/lib/psqlodbcw.so
Setup=/usr/lib/libodbcpsqlS.so
Driver64=/usr/lib64/psqlodbcw.so
Setup64=/usr/lib64/libodbcpsqlS.so
FileUsage=1

[MySQL]
Description=ODBC for MySQL
Driver=/usr/lib/libmyodbc5.so
Setup=/usr/lib/libodbcmyS.so
Driver64=/usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so
Setup64=/usr/lib64/libodbcmyS.so
FileUsage=1

[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.3.so.1.1
UsageCount=1

[FreeTDS]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so.0
UsageCount=1
```

Comment: The error message doesn't seem to correlate with the code presented. Any chance you have a `freetds.conf` file that has `[global]` or server-specific settings including `mutual authentication`, `use lanman` or `use ntlm2`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I have updated the question with `conf` file contents. seems like it has only the global part

Comment: What happens if you change `use ntlmv2 = yes` to `use ntlmv2 = no`? Note: this is a global setting, so it will affect all of your applications on that machine using FreeTDS.